# Linux using tar and if else when it has a file or not

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a simple problem. I want that this script will say that if tar has a file inside "echo tar successful!" else "echo don't have any files".

This is my script:

```
stat -c"%z;%n" * | grep '^2013-12-04' |  awk -F';' '{ print $2 }' |  xargs tar -zcvf file.tar.gz
if[]??
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

if it is successful

echo $? will return 0

otherwise it will return non-zero value.

other option is tar -tvf, that will test the archive. based on the return value from tar -tvf. you can check the list of your files. but if it is a huge file, you may need to check the first few files using head -n.

this is a good reference
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html
exmaple

you can add something like this to your bash script. (just hard coded the tar file)

tar -xvf test.tar > /dev/null

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]

then

echo "successful"

else

echo "error"

fi

Hope this helps

Tharanga Abeyseela

Answer (score 0):

```
function test_tar {
   if [[ $(tar -ztvf $1 | wc -l) != 0 ]]; then echo 'tar successful!'; else echo "don't have any files"; fi
}

$ test_tar non_empty_tar
tar successful!
$ test_tar empty_tar
don't have any files
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in your script.

```
stat -c "%z;%n" * | grep '^2013-12-04' | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | xargs tar -zcvf file.tar.gz 
if [[ $(zcat file.tar.gz | tar -tf - | wc -l) != 0 ]]; then 
    echo 'tar successful!'
else 
    echo "don't have any files"
fi
```